# Making fire using a filled water bottle

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, energy, visible-light

I have seen videos where a fire was started using a water bottle filled with water. I guess the bottle acts like a convex lens that converges light to a focal point to start a fire. But why does water have to be added?

Comment: a mainstay of survival topics e.g: http://www.instructables.com/id/7-Methods-of-Primitive-Fire-Starting/, http://graywolfsurvival.com/3137/creative-ways-start-fire-without-lighter/

Answer (score 7):

It's the water itself that forms the lens.  [Lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)) work via [refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction).  The [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) of water is about 1.333, which is different from the refractive index of air (about 1.0), so rays of light bend at the junction of the air and the water.